# Silverlight WCF services: WCF is accessed through Client?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis

Does a WCF service get called from the IIS server hosting the silverlight XAP or directly from the client's browser?  If you were to put your WCF services on a server closer to your database (and not the same server as your Silverlight / ASP.NET page), would the WCF server's ports need to be opened to the world?

It may be sound like a simple answer, but really it's not as obvious as it sounds for example:

> 1. ClientAccessPolicy.xml
>
> This file helps you control which
>   domains have access to call your WCF
>   service. Here is a very basic example
>   of how you can restrict access to only
>   those applications running under your
>   desired domain. This permits someone
>   running your Silverlight application
>   from both a secure and a non-secure
>   url.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <access-policy>
> <cross-domain-access>
> <policy>
> <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
> <domain uri="https://www.yourwebsite.com"/>
> <domain uri="http://www.yourwebsite.com"/>
> </allow-from>
> <grant-to>
> <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
> </grant-to>
> </policy>
> </cross-domain-access>
> </access-policy>
> ```

Sounds as if the call goes back to the web server which hosts the Silverlight application and then to the WCF service.

**Additional:**
I understand that I may not have communicated my question well.

If you have a server that you use for your WCF server (**Server A**)
and a server hosting your Silverlight application (**Server B**)

Does your client directly call **Server A** or does it make a request to **Server B** which is used as a proxy to communicate with **Server A**?

**Server A** is on one domain, **Server B** is on another domain, and **Client** is through the internet.

Comment: The XAP accesses the WFC service directly.  You can host a Silverlight application on Server A and have the WCF services on Server B.  A client can get the XAP from Server A and communicate with the WCF services on Server B.  You can shut down IIS on Server A and as long as the client keeps the XAP file open locally, will be unaware of the Sever A's status.

Answer (score 0):

In silverlight, the silverlight app runs completely in the context of the browser.  The only communication allowed in a normal, internet deployed silverlight app is via services.

It's still nice to have the WCF service as close to the database as possible, but that has nothing to do with the silverlight part of the scenario.

Comment: So the client browser directly calls the WCF services or does it get routed back to the server hosting the Silverlight application?

Comment: In the general case, a Silverlight application can consume services from just about anywhere.  In your scenario, if you happen to be hosting the WCF services on the same instance of IIS, nothing really changes.  There is no special "routing" that takes place.  It just happens to be pointed at the same place that your silverlight file is served from.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight can't host services, even in-proc, at least not as far as I'm aware. Your service will be hosted in IIS alongside the ASP.NET application which probably hosts your Silverlight  tag.

Regarding where you place your service, unless you have good reason to believe it belongs on the database server, don't do it. I would liken this to writing stored procs with business logic because you're concerned with the amount of data being transferred from your database - it's usually something you resort to when you have an actual need, not a hypothetical one.

Even if this is something you wish to do, consider that the data will always have to go through your application server.

Comment: No, I don't want to host the WCF service on the same server as the database.  But I do want to host it closer to the database - our database servers are not in the same building / state that we're in.

Comment: I suppose a lot of that depends on what you're doing. Understand that you will be adding complexity if you leave the same app pool model. You may not be gaining much performance.